# Python change list to set in code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im looking for a function that given a stringlist, i get the words and the indexes off the lines in which the words are:

example

```
s = ['this is the first document',
'this is the second document',
'and this is a third document',
'perhaps there should be a fourth document',
'and now there is a fifth too']
```

When i apply my function

```
def makeInverseIndex(s):

    dic={}
    index=0
    for line in s:
        set=line.split()
        for palabra in set:
            if palabra in dic:
                dic[palabra]=dic[palabra]+[index]
            else:
                dic[palabra]=[index]
        index+=1


    return dic
```

I am obtaining

```
{'a': [2, 3, 4], 'first': [0], 'the': [0, 1], 'and': [2, 4], 'there': [3, 4], 'perhaps': [3], 'document': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'should': [3], 'is': [0, 1, 2, 4], 'be': [3], 'fourth': [3], 'third': [2], 'second': [1], 'too': [4], 'fifth': [4], 'now': [4], 'this': [0, 1, 2]}
```

but i would like to obtain

```
{'a': {2, 3, 4}, 'first': {0}, 'the': {0, 1}, 'and': {2, 4}, 'there': {3, 4}, 'perhaps': {3}, 'document': {0, 1, 2, 3}, 'should': {3}, 'is': {0, 1, 2, 4}, 'be': {3}, 'fourth': {3}, 'third': {2}, 'second': {1}, 'too': {4}, 'fifth': {4}, 'now': {4}, 'this': {0, 1, 2}}
```

What do i have to change in my code? I have read about the difference between list and set, im using set to try to obtain {} but its not working

Thank you all

Comment: what do you mean you're "using set"? Just calling something `set` is very different from making object of the `set` type!

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i meant that my output has to be a dictionary that maps each word in any document to the set consisting of the document ids (ie, the index in the strlist) for all documents containing the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.setdefault`:

```
def makeInverseIndex(s):
    dic={}
    for index, line in enumerate(s):  #use enumerate() for getting index as well as item
        words = line.split()
        for palabra in words:
            dic.setdefault(palabra,set()).add(index)
```

Don't use `set` as a variable name, as it hides the built-in function `set()`.

Comment: The output continue being the same :$

Comment: @TomeuOliverArbona That's not possible, BTW the syntax `{1,2}` for sets was introduced in py3.x, so in case you're using py2.x then you'll see something like `set([1,2])`.

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe for me wasnt working because using the Shell, everything is so bad. Thank you,

Comment: Which program to work with python should i use instead of the Python 3.3.2 Idle ? Thanks

Comment: @Zipp For running scripts there are many IDEs available like geany, eclipse, pycharm etc. For interactive shell I'd suggest IPython shell.

Comment: Agreed, `IPython` is simply awesome. You can also integrate it with `pdb` through the `ipdb` module to obtain pretty powerful debugging capabilities as well..